# How to enter some values in installation wizard in c#

Tags: c#, windows, installation

So what I need is to make the installation wizard that will prompt user to enter some values before he installs his product. For example I need to set the COM port so I would need from user to enter the right COM port and I want to pass that value to C#.

Is this possible? Same thing is for the serial key for example. How to make that? Are there any tools? What technology I need to use and so on..So please give me your ideas and experiences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) to create custom dialogs in your setup wizard. (The Setup project in VS does not support it.)

See [*New Link in the Chain*](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain) article of WiX tutorial, it addresses adding a new dialog to collect registration information.

Similarly you can add other dialogs to your setup wizard if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the VS installer projects and they are nice, but when it comes to custom actions a bit difficult. I switched to Wix and I was able to do a lot of custom things (including UI customizations, web sites installations, COM registrations, MSMQ, etc.) which would have been difficult with VS installers. However, Wix has a considerable learning curve.